# Why don't TypeScript throw any error when interface not properly implemented?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a class that implements the interface. If a class does not include the method which interface requires a typescript compiler is not throwing error but executes the error.

I want to enforce the compiler to throw an error if error is missing.

```
interface PersonInterface {
  name: string;  
  age: number;  
}
class Person implements PersonInterface {    
  name: string = 'Mary';  
  foo: any = 'abc';
}

alert(new Person().name)
```

You can check the code here at the playground
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=31#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsQElzTxLIDeAsAFDLIhwC2EAXMhmFKAOYDc1l1cHJjQCudAEbQeySgF9KCADZwMGNJhzJgdAA4KIDcKvRRseArEQoS1XlRr0hrdiA7IAvMgDkAWThQAnp5SfMgwWFjMcCD+7l5wYghBspTyONh6AHQKWBwAFCAQAO5qJji5AJQZtAzlQA

Codesandbox LINK : https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-3bqq4?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. The code in the playground throws a compiler error.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen the above example should give an error but it simply runs without throwing any error. The compiler only makes Error line RED that's all. Even with the error, the CODE is running successfully. Please check the codesandbox link carefully then you will understand what I mean.

Comment: You understand that TypeScript is only a compile-time construct, right? Once it compiles into JavaScript, all the type-checking goes out the window. The entire goal of TypeScript is to catch as many possible problems at compile-time. Plenty of TypeScript compile-time errors will not translate into JavaScript runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the playground errors out for age property and this is how you can type a method.

- Typing a method

```
interface PersonInterface {
  name: string;  
  age: number;

  // type a method
  sayHello(): string

  // type function property
  repeat: (sentence: string) => string
}

class Person implements PersonInterface {    
  name: string = 'Mary';  
  foo: any = 'abc';

  sayHello() {
    return `Hello my name is ${this.name}`
  }

  repeat = (input) => {
    return `${input}`
  }
}
```

If you want it to error out you should consider using abstract class, One thing to note is that you can't instantiate an abstract class. [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

```
abstract class PERSON {
  abstract name: string;
  abstract age: number;
  abstract repeat(sentence: string): string;
}

class Person extends PERSON{
  //
  // Will error out for not implementing
  // properties and methods
  //
}
```

Errors will be gone

```
class Person extends PERSON {
  constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {
    super();
  }

  repeat(input: string) {
    return `${input}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi I do not want the error to be gone. I want the typescript to validate and throw an error. Which it is not throwing the error at the moment. It simply runs the example. You can check the code sandbox link i shared above.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You solved my issue. Abstract class is the solution.

Comment: I gave a down-vote because this does not answer the initial question, but just suggest a workaround / explains how you could write the code differently. But it does not answer the question "why" does it "not" throw