# TypeScript does not throw when interface and class have the same name. Can someone explain why, or is this a TS bug?

Tags: typescript, class, interface

TypeScript does not throw when interface and class have the same name.

Can someone explain why, or is this a TS bug?

Why does following TypeScript not throw any compile time errors?

```
interface MyService {
  x: number;
  readonly m1: () => void;
  m2(): void;
}

class MyService {
  y: number = 0;
  // Maybe alternatively here could a compile time error be thrown (?)
}

const a: MyService = new MyService(); // MyService (interface) and MyService (class) gets merged!

// a.m2 = () => {}

a.m1(); // I expect compile time error
a.m2(); // I expect compile time error
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DK0BuwnIDeAsAFDLIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANxkVQRwAmA9iAA26ZIwCMtABQBKZAF4AfMhz9gvDuTEAmWbVXrNAXzJkEQuAGdLaLLnwoSW9LQYtoC5AAZjp0gkFLMGQ4WgxsKDwCeToIAHdbCKiIWU0yAHp0kIA6Rm1PWQVlQhNSMjhc8VTy3N0ZNiA)

Please note that this is not a duplicate to [Typescript Class implement Interface if method is missing compiler not throwing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62420892/typescript-class-implement-interface-if-method-is-missing-compiler-not-throwing) because I **don't** use `implements` in this case!

```
- interface MyService {
+ interface AMyService {

- const a: MyService = new MyService();
+ const a: AMyService = new MyService(); // This would throw!
```

Comment: This is [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), a feature of TypeScript (not a bug).  Class declarations bring into scope a named interface corresponding to class instances, and you can re-open that interface to add or overload members.  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: `Does that fully address the question?` Only partly. I still feel like missing why because of that no compile time error is thrown. Maybe you have an example for when this is useful?

Comment: No compiler error is thrown because it's intentionally a way to represent functionality that is expected to be present at runtime but not compiled in TypeScript, or not done in the standard way (e.g., via modifying the `prototype`, as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/w22o9w)). For example, you could use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to extend native classes this way (not that this is recommended).  So does that suffice now (and I will plan to write an answer) or are there still outstanding issues (and I will wait)?

Comment: Using `MyService.prototype.m1 = () => {}` also throws a compile time error (because of the readonly) but I start to see what you mean. So if for example someone extends the class in another file via prototype, then this could be a way. Then I write type declarations for that (because e.g. they are missing). Yeah I think I would give you an upvote for an answer and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, a declaration creates entities in at least one of three groups: namespace, type, or value. Namespace-creating declarations create a namespace, which contains names that are accessed using a dotted notation. Type-creating declarations do just that: they create a type that is visible with the declared shape and bound to the given name. Lastly, value-creating declarations create values that are visible in the output JavaScript.

Therefore, interfaces and classes can have the same name because they are in different namespaces.

Please note that not all merges are allowed in TypeScript. Currently, classes can not merge with other classes or with variables, but they can with Interfaces.

When you define an interface with the same name as a class, the interface declaration creates a new type, while the class declaration creates a new value with the same name. These two are distinct entities, and they can coexist in the same namespace without conflict.

When you create an instance of the `MyService` class using the `new` keyword and assign it to the variable a, you can call both `m1` and `m2` methods on it, because the instance has both methods defined by the interface.

---

Read more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: But it would always result in a runtime error, would it? Or is there a way where e.g. `m1` could be defined lazy (in TS, without errors) even when it is `readonly`?

Comment: `(MyService.prototype as Writable<MyService>).m1 = () => {/*whatever*/}`. In JS you may do literally anything you can think about, without caring of TS. And in TS you may try to maky types for that